# Wubi install fail because of "substring not found"

Tags: 12.04, installation, wubi

Every time I try to install Wubi, I get a missing substring

last parts of the install log always state the same thing "substring not found".

Thoughts?

last part of wubi-12.04.3-rev279:

```
10-07 20:52 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: total size=30000
  root=29744
  swap=256
  home=0
  usr=0
10-07 20:52 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished choose_disk_sizes
10-07 20:52 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running expand_diskimage...
10-07 20:53 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished expand_diskimage
10-07 20:53 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running create_swap_diskimage...
10-07 20:53 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished create_swap_diskimage
10-07 20:53 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running modify_bootloader...
10-07 20:53 DEBUG  TaskList: New task modify_bcd
10-07 20:53 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Running modify_bcd...
10-07 20:53 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: modify_bcd Drive(C: hd 785689.058594 mb free ntfs)
10-07 20:53 ERROR  TaskList: substring not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\backend.py", line 695, in modify_bcd
ValueError: substring not found
10-07 20:53 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
10-07 20:53 DEBUG  TaskList: New task modify_bcd
10-07 20:53 ERROR  root: substring not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 132, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 158, in run_installer
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\backend.py", line 695, in modify_bcd
ValueError: substring not found
10-07 20:53 DEBUG  TaskList: New task modify_bcd
10-07 20:53 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished modify_bootloader
10-07 20:53 DEBUG  TaskList: # Finished tasklist
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the failure ([reference](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-installer/wubi/trunk/view/head:/src/wubi/backends/win32/backend.py#L693)):

```
command = [bcdedit, '/create', '/d', '%s' % self.info.distro.name, '/application', 'bootsector']
id = run_command(command)
id = id[id.index('{'):id.index('}')+1]
```

So basically it's running the command:

```
bcdedit /create /d Ubuntu /application bootsector
```

which is supposed to add an entry to the Windows Boot Manager (BCD Store) for Ubuntu and return a response that contains the GUID for the entry e.g.

```
{2e05fa55-5f6e-11e2-a7cc-95d88d2d9736}
```

But it seems that the command fails. The third line is the line outputting that error `ValueError: substring not found`.

So I'd begin by exploring why you can't add an entry to the BCD store.